# cmake add_custom_target escaping

Tags: c++, c, cmake, escaping

Here is minimal `CMakeLists.txt` to reproduce problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9 FATAL_ERROR)

set(BUILD_INFO_CPP "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build_info.cpp")
add_custom_target(GenerateBuildInfo ALL
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "#include Something" > "${BUILD_INFO_CPP}"
)
```

On every build I want regenerate `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build_info.cpp`,
but this code not create `build_info.cpp`, because of `cmake` execute it like this:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E echo #include > /tmp/2/build/build_info.cpp
```

and as understand shell interpret `#` as start of comments, so this is equivalent to

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E echo
```

I wonder is special symbols escaping not implemented in `cmake`?

I use linux/bash and Makefile generator.

Comment: Have you tried `-E echo \"#include Something\" > \"${BUILD_INFO_CPP}\"`?

Comment: @Pablo This is not helps, `cmake` eat quotes. But looks like `VERBATIM` works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation for [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) (CMake 3.0):

> If VERBATIM is given **then all arguments to the commands will be escaped properly for the build tool so that the invoked command receives each argument unchanged**. Note that one level of escapes is still used by the CMake language processor before add_custom_target even sees the arguments. Use of VERBATIM is recommended as it enables correct behavior. **When VERBATIM is not given the behavior is platform specific because there is no protection of tool-specific special characters.**

Thus, add `VERBATIM` so that the command is properly escaped in `add_custom_target`.

The same applies for all versions onwards and CMake 2.8 as well.